# Snakemake: How to dynamically set memory resource based on input file size

Tags: snakemake

I'm trying to base my cluster memory allocation for a given rule on the file size of an input file. Is this possible in snakemake and if so how?

So far I have tried specifying it in the `resource:` section like so:

```
rule compute2:
    input: "input1.txt"
    output: "input2.txt"
    resources:
        mem_mb=lambda wildcards, input, attempt: int(os.path.getsize(str(input))/(1024*1024))
    shell: "touch input2.txt"
```

But it seems snakemake attempts to calculate this upfront before the file gets created as I'm getting this error:

```
InputFunctionException in line 35 of test_snakemake/Snakefile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'input1.txt'
```

Im running my snakemake with the following command:

```
snakemake --verbose -j 10 --cluster-config cluster.json --cluster "sbatch -n {cluster.n} -t {cluster.time} --mem {resources.mem_mb}"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this dynamically per rule as per the question, you can use something along these lines:

`resources: mem_mb=lambda wildcards, input, attempt: (input.size//1000000) * attempt * 10`

Where `input.size//1000000` is used convert the cumulative size of input files in bytes to mb, and the tailing `10` could be any arbitrary number based on the specifics of your shell/script requirements.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using the `--default-resources` option. As explained in Snakemake's --help information:

> In addition to plain integers, python expressions over input size are
> allowed (e.g. `'2*input.size_mb'`). When specifying this without any
> arguments (`--default-resources`), it defines
> `'mem_mb=max(2*input.size_mb, 1000)''disk_mb=max(2*input.size_mb, 1000)'`,
> i.e., default disk and mem usage is twice the input file size
> but at least 1GB.