# Snakemake, slurm and memory

Tags: memory, resources, slurm, snakemake

I am struggling to understand how snakemake submits jobs to slurm.

When I have a basic slurm sbatch script I usually add a line, such as
`#SBATCH --mem=5G`
to determine that slurm may use 5 gigabytes (and no more) of memory.

Now, I am using snakemake together with slurm with `snakemake --configfile config.yaml --snakefile test.smk --profile simple/.` The profil file looks like this:

```
cluster:
  mkdir -p logs &&
  sbatch
    --partition={resources.partition}
    --cpus-per-task={threads}
    --gpus={resources.gpus}
    --mem={resources.mem_mb}
    --time={resources.runtime}
    --job-name={rule}
    --output=logs/{rule}.out
    --error=logs/{rule}.err
    --parsable 

default-resources:
  - partition=batch
  - runtime=10 
  - nodes=1 

slurm: True
```

Now, most of the time I do not define resources in my snakemake rules, so it's just using the defaults (whatever those are?). However, I noticed that when an input files to a snakemake rule is fairly large (or I am imputing several larger files at once) I often get an error at startup similar to **slurm submission failed, cannot satisfy memory specification** and snakemake stops before it can get started. I then need to manually specify the memory as done in this rule:

```
for plevel in plevels:
# PURPOSE: Link the previously generated ec.bin files to speed up hic runs.
    rule:
        name: f"run_link_bin_{plevel}"
        input:
            hifiasm_bin=expand("{output_directory}/hifi/hifiasm/{species_lower}.ec.bin", output_directory=config["output_directory"], species_lower=config["species_lower"]), 
            hifiasm_bin_reverse=expand("{output_directory}/hifi/hifiasm/{species_lower}.ovlp.reverse.bin", output_directory=config["output_directory"], species_lower=config["species_lower"]),
            hifiasm_bin_source=expand("{output_directory}/hifi/hifiasm/{species_lower}.ovlp.source.bin", output_directory=config["output_directory"], species_lower=config["species_lower"]), 
        output:
            ln_hifiasm_bin=expand("{output_directory}/hic/hifiasm/purge_level_{plevel}/{species_lower}.ec.bin", output_directory=config["output_directory"], species_lower=config["species_lower"], plevel=plevel), 
            ln_hifiasm_bin_reverse=expand("{output_directory}/hic/hifiasm/purge_level_{plevel}/{species_lower}.ovlp.reverse.bin", output_directory=config["output_directory"], species_lower=config["species_lower"], plevel=plevel),
            ln_hifiasm_bin_source=expand("{output_directory}/hic/hifiasm/purge_level_{plevel}/{species_lower}.ovlp.source.bin", output_directory=config["output_directory"], species_lower=config["species_lower"], plevel=plevel),         
        message: "Message: Link the previously generated ec.bin files to sped up re-run."
        resources:
            slurm_partition=bigmem, 
            mem_mb=1000000, # pointless here, but snakemake sees the large input size and wants more memory
        shell:
            """
            ln -s {input.hifiasm_bin} {output.ln_hifiasm_bin}
            ln -s {input.hifiasm_bin_reverse} {output.ln_hifiasm_bin_reverse}
            ln -s {input.hifiasm_bin_source} {output.ln_hifiasm_bin_source}
            """
```

As I am sure, you noticed allocating so much memory in this case, makes absolutely no sense, as the rule just soft links some (albeit fairly large) files. However, if I dont, snakmake cannot not start running this rule.
So I guess my question is, how much memory does snakmake automatically request in a slurm job if the `mem_mb` parameter is not set within the rule? It seems to depend on the input file size? And what would be the best practice in this case?

Comment: Not positive about the memory allocation, in my experience I set usage per rule and don't rely on defaults.  For your linking rule, consider setting it to a [`localrule`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#local-rules)

Answer (score 1):

First, use the [slurm executor](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cluster.html#executing-on-slurm-clusters).

If no resources are specified, `snakemake` uses [defaults](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#default-resources)). Those errors with large files are because `snakemake` default memory resource will be `2*input.size_mb` (and that might be more than you have in your cluster).

Answer (score 0):

> So I guess my question is, how much memory does snakmake automatically request in a slurm job if the mem_mb parameter is not set within the rule?

I don't think snakemake allocates any resources automatically. If `mem_mb` is not present in a rule's `resources.mem_mb`, then snakemake will use whatever you have in default-resources, and if there is no entry for `mem_mb` in default resources then the sbatch job will be submitted without `--mem` option and you will get whatever the cluster administrator has set as default.

I don't claim this to be a *best practice*, just a suggestion:

- Set `mem_mb` in default-resources to a sensible default
- For rules that need exceptionally high or low memory set mem_mb in those rules (it doesn't need to be an exact estimate as long as it is enough and not too much)
- For dynamically allocating memory based on input size see also this question [Snakemake: How to dynamically set memory resource based on input file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50891407/snakemake-how-to-dynamically-set-memory-resource-based-on-input-file-size)